# Using layout_above in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Can someone explain to me why the ImageView is not appearing above the LinearLayout?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rev_main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!-- some stuff in here -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rev_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_above="@id/rev_main"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't get it.

Comment: Does it appear anywhere? nowhere at all? maybe post a pic of how it looks and it it would be easier to tell why. In my Layouts I use IDs like "@+id/rev_main" Even in the attributes like layout_above. Truthfully though Im not even sure of the difference between the two, perhaps try that?

Comment: It disappears.  If I declare the ImageView first and try to make the LinearLayout position itself above the ImageView, the LinearLayout disappears as well.

Comment: Just FYI - had this problem inside listview item layout. After I applied fixed height for item layout, the problem went away.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This happens when you specify alignment relative to another layout.  The solution I found was to go the other direction.

Instead of telling the ImageView to be above the LinearLayout, tell the LinearLayout to be below the ImageView.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rev_main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rev_arrow">
        <!-- some stuff in here -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rev_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Here's my problem with this: The drawable used for the ImageView changes. Which means I need a variable for it in code. The position (above or below) the LinearLayout also changes. If I need to edit the LayoutParams for the LinearLayout, that means I also need a variable for the LinearLayout. I was hoping to just need a variable for the ImageView.

Comment: Well, variables are cheap.  Alternatively, you could create two image views, 1 above & 1 below and set the initial state to android:visibility="gone".  Then you could programatically change the visibility state of each view based on your needs.

Comment: Don't you also need to move the rev_arrow ImageView above the LinearLayout in the xml? Otherwise you'll get a reference error since the file is parsed linearly. I just ran into that issue. :-P

Comment: I have one view positioned aligned to some other view and want to have some other view above it: I have to use `layout_above`. Solved it by putting the two to a `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 7):

The following should work for you:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rev_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rev_main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/rev_arrow"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!-- some stuff in here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have a problem with this. Sometimes I want the LinearLayout above the ImageView.  When I change the attribute on the LinearLayout to layout_above, the LinearLayout disappears entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I had an similar problem by creating a custom optionsMenu. The simplest way to set z-order of views was to do it programmatically. If you want to switch the order sometimes, your should easily call:

```
    ImageView yourImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.rev_arrow);
    yourImageView.bringToFront();
```

I don´t know if it is adaptive to your application, but in my case it works perfect. If you need more code, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you have such problem in ListView make sure that you use proper inflation method. Parent view group must be specified for correct inflation.

```
mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
```

**Don't use**

```
mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
```