# Imaging view height extend the whole application

Tags: android, xml

I have two 3 buttons , 2 on the top corners , and one on the bottom center. and one imageView in the middle of the page , Now i need the imageView's height to be extended to down without overriding the button , and i need the imageView's width to fit the screen of any android device. NOT : I NEED THE IMAGEVIEW SIZE TO BE FIXED REGARDLESS OF THE IMAGE.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/share"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:onClick="share"
    android:padding="5dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/next"
    android:onClick="next" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
     android:minHeight="50dp"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
    android:background="@drawable/download"
    android:onClick="download" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
 android:minHeight="50dp"
 android:adjustViewBounds="true" /
```

just set the size in the width and height
and regrading ur other question u need to use RelativeLayout

example :

[RelativeLayout Above Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970773/using-layout-above-in-a-relativelayout)